# Setting custom marker image would overlay default marker icon along with custom icon

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, maps, marker

After updating version of forms to 2.4.0.282, I started getting this weird behavior in `MapView`. I have created a custom renderer for map in android where I am setting marker images as per my requirement. Custom markers in fact appear, but on top of it, it's default icon still gets overlaid.

Note that I am using Xamarin.Maps version 2.4.0.282, tried to downgrade to prior versions as well but I am of no help.

I even tried it out by commenting line,

> Forms.SetFlags("FastRenderers_Experimental");

but even this didn't help.

Below is the renderer I created,

```
public class CustomMapRenderer : MapRenderer, IOnMapReadyCallback
    {
        GoogleMap map;

        public static double PreviousDistance = 0;

        List<CustomPin> customPins;

        CustomMap formsMap = null;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ElementChangedEventArgs<Map> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement != null)
            {
                map.InfoWindowClick -= OnInfoWindowClick;
                map.MarkerClick -= OnMarkerClick;
            }

            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                formsMap = (CustomMap)e.NewElement;
                customPins = formsMap.CustomPins;
                ((MapView)Control).GetMapAsync(this);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
        {
            map = googleMap;
            map.InfoWindowClick += OnInfoWindowClick;

            map.MarkerClick += OnMarkerClick;

            map.UiSettings.ZoomControlsEnabled = false;

            formsMap.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(formsMap.Location, Distance.FromMiles(1.0)));

            if(customPins != null && customPins.Count > 0)
            {
                setMapPins("CustomPins");
            }
        }

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

            if (e.PropertyName == "CustomPins" || (e.PropertyName.Equals("VisibleRegion")))
            {
                setMapPins(e.PropertyName);
            }
        }

        private void setMapPins(string PropertyName)
        {
            customPins = formsMap.CustomPins;

            map.Clear();

            if (customPins != null && customPins.Count > 0)
            {
                if (PropertyName == "CustomPins")
                {
                    //Set map zoom
                    var defaultZoom = 14;

                    try
                    {
                        PreviousDistance = DistanceCalculation.MoveToRegionData.MoveToRegion(formsMap, customPins, defaultZoom, PreviousDistance);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        PreviousDistance = 0;
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    }
                }

                foreach (var pin in customPins)
                {
                    var pinImage = Resources.GetIdentifier(pin.PinImage.ToLower(), "drawable", Context.PackageName);
                    var markerImg = BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromResource(pinImage);

                    map.AddMarker(new MarkerOptions().SetTitle(pin.Pin.Label).SetSnippet(pin.Id).SetPosition(new LatLng(pin.Pin.Position.Latitude, pin.Pin.Position.Longitude)).SetIcon(markerImg));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("In else!!");
            }
        }

        protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
        {
            base.OnLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);

            if (changed)
            {
            }
        }

        void OnInfoWindowClick(object sender, GoogleMap.InfoWindowClickEventArgs e)
        {
            var customPin = GetCustomPin(e.Marker);
            if (customPin == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Custom pin not found");
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(customPin.Url))
            {
                var url = global::Android.Net.Uri.Parse(customPin.Url);
                var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, url);
                intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.NewTask);
                global::Android.App.Application.Context.StartActivity(intent);
            }
        }

        CustomPin GetCustomPin(Marker annotation)
        {
            var position = new Position(annotation.Position.Latitude, annotation.Position.Longitude);
            foreach (var pin in customPins)
            {
                if (pin.Pin.Position == position)
                {
                    return pin;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        void OnMarkerClick(object sender, GoogleMap.MarkerClickEventArgs ea)
        {   
            var marker = (Marker) ea.Marker;
            formsMap.IsPinClicked = false;

            var customPin = GetCustomPin(marker);
            if (customPin == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Custom pin not found");
            }
            formsMap.SelectedPinId = Convert.ToInt32(marker.Snippet);
            formsMap.IsPinClicked = true;
        }
    }
```

This is what it looks like right now..

[image]

Comment: Did you clear the native map before you add new icons? And please could you provide detailed codes or a basic demo that can reproduce the problem?

Comment: @ElvisXia-MSFT, Yes I did. I have also edited my post. Hope this may help you figure out the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have created a custom renderer for map in android where I am setting marker images as per my requirement. Custom markers in fact appear, but on top of it, it's default icon still gets overlaid.

I've made a demo and reproduced the problem, after some tests I found that the overriding of `OnMapReady` function causes the problem. Even with totally empty `OnMapReady` the problem will occurs. My guess is a call to the `OnMapReady` in Custom Map Render might lead to a rerender of the Map including pins.

**Solution:**

1. Comment `OnMapReady` out.
2. Move the logic in `OnMapReady` to `OnElementChanged`.
3. Let your local variable `map=NativeMap` and make sure `setMapPins` get called in `OnElementPropertyChanged`.

Comment: Well that's brilliant. Upon reading your solution, I did made few changes in my code, Commented out OnMapReady, made changes in OnElementPropertyChanged. Few quick checks shows when pins are being drawn, default pins flicker for fraction of seconds and then go away, but it any way serves the purpose. Thanks a lot. You save me :-)

Answer (score 1):

Add **NativeMap.Clear();** in **OnElementPropertyChanged** and try again. Hope it will help!!!

Have a look below code for customizing pin on Android Platform.

```
[assembly:ExportRenderer (typeof(CustomMap), typeof(CustomMapRenderer))]
namespace CustomRenderer.Droid
{
    public class CustomMapRenderer : MapRenderer, GoogleMap.IInfoWindowAdapter
    {
        List<CustomPin> customPins;
        bool isDrawn;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ElementChangedEventArgs<View> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement != null)
            {
                NativeMap.InfoWindowClick -= OnInfoWindowClick;
            }

            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                var formsMap = (CustomMap)e.NewElement;
                customPins = formsMap.CustomPins;
                ((MapView)Control).GetMapAsync(this);
            }
        }


        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

            if (e.PropertyName.Equals("VisibleRegion") && !isDrawn)
            {
                NativeMap.Clear();
                NativeMap.InfoWindowClick += OnInfoWindowClick;
                NativeMap.SetInfoWindowAdapter(this);

                foreach (var pin in customPins)
                {
                    var marker = new MarkerOptions();
                    marker.SetPosition(new LatLng(pin.Pin.Position.Latitude, pin.Pin.Position.Longitude));
                    marker.SetTitle(pin.Pin.Label);
                    marker.SetSnippet(pin.Pin.Address);
                    marker.SetIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromResource(Resource.Drawable.pin));

                    NativeMap.AddMarker(marker);
                }
                isDrawn = true;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

For more detail [Click here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/map/customized-pin/)

Comment: Yes, I applied identical solution and it seems to be working as per my expectation. Appreciate your efforts towards providing the solution. Thanks :-)